# Why is my Availability Group in an unhealthy state and showing synchronizing?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, failover

I have an active directory and 3 SQL Server nodes in an availability group.

The primary and secondary node are on different subnet to active directory: 104.92.173.x

The third node which is in async commit mode, is on the same subnet as active directory: 104.92.174.x

[image]

I don't see anything in the error log on SQL Server, but my availability group is in an unhealthy state and availability replicas are stuck at synchronizing state.

[image]

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: I think this is expected since the asynchronous node is primary.  Since it's asynchronous, it does not wait on the synchronous nodes before committing, so the synchronous nodes are always just a bit out of sync, thus the warning message.

Comment: Your primary is set to Manual failover - this means that it is in Asyc mode. Change the primary to Sync and automatic failover to see the dashboard green.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @TonyHinkle actually i changed the primary and secondary on the same subnet to sync and the other one to async

Comment: @KinShah thanks for your comment i changed the db to sync mode

Comment: @1AmirJalali, with those modification, is it still in problem ? If so, could you please check in the AG to see if the data movement is suspended (expend Availabilty Group then database). Also, can you add the server name in your first printscreen so that we know which one is in primary site vs secondary site.